# Macports and LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX

Tags: clang, macports, xcode10

I use to bundle Macports libraries from /opt/local/lib into my application (with corrected load paths via install_name_tool).

With Xcode 10, this app gets rejected during upload to the Apple App Store, because the dylibs from Macports no longer contain the Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX command. Older versions of Macports-delivered binaries contained it, as can be seen from

`otool -l /opt/local/libHalf.dylib | grep LC_VERSION`

How can I bring LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX back into Macports-delivered shared libraries?

Comment: There is `-macosx_version_min 10.12` linker flag either as an argument for `ld` or `gcc`. Does `Macports` build the libraries from sources? Perhaps `brew` instead of `Macports` could also be an alternative.

Comment: Yeah I know about the flags, since my App's own binaries are built with it and contain `LC_VERSION_MACOSX`. Brew, however, behaves like MacPorts in not setting -macosx_version_min during build.